# Disable Save and SaveAs buttons when opening Word using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, ribbon

In the office project added below code in ribbon xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2010/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <commands>
    <command idMso="FileSaveAs" enabled="false" />
    <command idMso="FileSave" enabled="false" />
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

and also added below line of code in ThisAddIn.cs

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            return new Ribbon1();
        }
```

Could you please tell me how it is getting called when I open Word document using asp.net. Currently disabling of requested buttons not working.